# Java, saved file in object, can't retrieve it

Tags: java, file, object, save, serializable

This was my first time ever trying to save object in a file, so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. This is just a test program, the original one is much larger. Save is successful, backup file is created. However I can't seem to recall that file/object. Compiling works though. Could someone please explain where exactly did I go wrong. And in a little bit more 'beginner tutorial' style please, I'm really bad with 'Serializable'

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class save {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, Person> list = new HashMap<String, Person>();

        Person person = new Person("12", "AAA", "XXX");
        list.put(person.getID(), person);

        if( list.containsKey(person.getID()))
            System.out.println(list.get(person.getID()));


        savePerson(person);

        list.remove(person.getID());

        if( list.containsKey(person.getID()))
            System.out.println(list.get(person.getID()));
        else
            System.out.println("Person is not available");

        person = loadPerson("12");

        System.out.println(list.size());

    }

    protected static void savePerson(Person person) {
        File source = new File("person"+person.getID()+".data");
        try { source.createNewFile(); } catch(IOException e) {System.out.println("Can't create new file : " +e.getMessage());}
        try {
            FileOutputStream personFile = new FileOutputStream("person"+person.getID()+".data");
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream personObj = new ObjectOutputStream (personFile);
                personObj.writeObject(person);
                personObj.close();
                personFile.close();
            } catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Can't save the object :" +e.getMessage());}

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("Can't read the damn file :" +e.getMessage());}

    }

    protected static Person loadPerson(String ID) {
        Person person = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream personFile = new FileInputStream("person"+ID+".data");
            try {
                ObjectInputStream personObj = new ObjectInputStream(personFile);
                try {
                    person = (Person)personObj.readObject();
                    personObj.close();
                    personFile.close();
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){System.out.println("Can't find the class :" +e.getMessage());}
            } catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Can't save the object :" +e.getMessage());}
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println("Can't read the damn file :" +e.getMessage());}
        return person;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the person class on the request:

```
import java.io.*;

class Person implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    public Person(String id, String fname, String lname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    protected String getID() { return id; }
    protected String getFname() { return fname; }
    protected String getLname() { return lname; }

    protected void setFname(String newFname) { fname = newFname; }

    public String toString() {
        return id + ", " + fname + " " + lname;
    }
}
```

Comment: You ignore quite a lot of exceptions there. Are you sure none of them is thrown?

Comment: Try to print e.getMessage() in all catches. You are never closing a file?

Comment: it might be a good idea to provide Person class as well. @vedran

Comment: @Zohaib I added person class, though I doubt that it's causing the whole problem

Comment: @AdamZalcman, yes, I tried all of them and didn't get a single error.

Comment: @Krishnanunni added e.getMessage(), as well as closed both file and object. Error still persists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close the file after writing to it. You probably don't get access to the file. Also, if you will fill the empty catch blocks with print of the exception, you'll be closer to find the problem.

You can close it by calling [`personFile.close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#close%28%29) (and the same after reading the object)

**EDIT:** I tested your (new) code, and it works just fine. I was able to read the object, but your code does nothing with it.

BTW, you don't need to close both stream, as stated in `close`:

> If this stream has an associated channel then the channel is closed as
>   well.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? Again, I apologize for the ignorance, but first year student here... :)

Comment: I added both personObj.close(); and personFile.close(); but nothing happens again...

Comment: I updated the code with closing statements, did I use them ate the right time? see original post

Comment: OK, so I forgot to put it back in HashMap, big deal... Joking aside, thanks for helping.